# Trigger onChange function even if an option is already chosen in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, select, react-hooks

I'm looking how to trigger onChange function when an option is already selected and clicked by the user to deselect it, it's like multiselect.
you can select an option and deselect it by clicking on it a second time.
this is what i've already tried.
everything is working when there is more than 1 option selected, but not when there is only one option selected.

```
const handleChangeGroup = (selectedItems) => {
    const groups = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
      if (groupArray.includes(selectedItems[i].value)) {
        if (groupArray.length === 0) {
          setGroupArray([]);
        } else {
          var newArray = groupArray.filter(
            (value) => value != selectedItems[i].value
          );
          setGroupArray(newArray);
        }
      } else {
        groups.push(selectedItems[i].value);
        setGroupArray(groupArray.concat(groups));
      }
    }
  };


<select
            multiple={true}
            value={groupArray}
            onChange={(event) =>
              handleChangeGroup(event.target.selectedOptions)
            }>
            {data[selectType] !== undefined
              ? Object.keys(data[selectType]).map((group, index) => (
                  <option value={group} key={group}>
                    {group}
                  </option>
                ))
              : null}
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Executable example:

```js
const Sample = () => {
    const data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    const [groupArray, setGroupArray] = React.useState([]);

    const handleChangeGroup = (selectedItem) => {
        if (groupArray.includes(selectedItem)) {
            const tempArray = groupArray.filter(item => item !== selectedItem);
            setGroupArray([...tempArray]);
        } else {
            setGroupArray([...groupArray, selectedItem]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <select
            multiple
            value={groupArray}
            onClick={e => handleChangeGroup(e.target.value)}
        >
            {data.map((group, index) => (
                <option value={group} key={group}>
                    {group}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Sample />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You might want to consider using checkboxes for a more intuitive UI and more concise code.

If you don't want to use checkboxes, you can use this code:

```
const handleChangeGroup = (selectedItem) => {
    if (groupArray.includes(selectedItem)) {
        const tempArray = groupArray.filter(item => item !== selectedItem);
        setGroupArray([...tempArray]);
    } else {
        setGroupArray([...groupArray, selectedItem]);
    }
};

return (
    <select
        multiple
        value={groupArray}
        onClick={e => handleChangeGroup(e.target.value)}
    >
        {data[selectType] !== undefined
            ? Object.keys(data[selectType]).map((group, index) => (
                <option value={group} key={group}>
                    {group}
                </option>
            ))
            : null}
    </select>
);
```

The reason `onChange` won't work is because the default behavior of select is to make the user choose at least one option. Clicking on the last selected option will not deselect anything. So `onChange` won't fire when you have only one selected item left. You can override this replacing `onChange` with `onClick`.

For a simpler example/test, you can try using select without the `multiple` attribute. Clicking on the currently selected option won't fire any deselect events either.

Comment: this is also not working

Comment: @Say0 Did you copy my exact code? You should copy `onClick={e => handleChangeGroup(e.target.value)}` and my `handleChangeGroup` function for it to work. Please include your whole code in your question so we can see where your errors are.

Comment: yes, i included all your changes , and it doesn't work, and  i already tried your solution and it didn't work, so that's why i have this code it's the last version that i could do, i can't put the whole code here due to the size of the code and the company confidentiality, thnaks for your help

Comment: @Say0 No problem! I still edited the answer in case other people view your question. I added a snippet to demo my code.